# Plot almost/standard library in c++?

Tags: c++, plot

Is there anything in std library or boost (or good enough libraries) which let me make good plots in c++? I would need something like matplotlib of python or gnuplot.
Thank you

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2509156/anyone-knows-a-matplotlib-equivalent-in-c-or-c

Comment: What's wrong with gnuplot?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a couple of "native" C++ libraries for plotting. The two I'm familiar with are:

- CERN's ROOT framework - This gives you a lot more than just plotting, and is specifically geared toward analysis of large amounts of data, but it does have a lot of fairly advanced plotting tools.
- MathGL - though not as powerful or as easy to use as ROOT, it provides a simple way to plot all but the most complex of plots.

There is nothing "standard " about these libraries, but they are both fairly well supported.